# How to make a POST request from inside a Restlet

Tags: android, post, httpclient, restlet, android-c2dm

I'm current using Restlet to interface with an Android app.

I want the Restlet on the server to then trigger a C2DM push message when it gets a certain POST from an Android app - it's basically just a simple HTTP POST to Google's servers with some extra values in it.

I imagine there must be some way of using the in built connector, or otherwise, anyone have any ideas? Can't seem to find anything about it on the net, an unusual request perhaps.

Edit: Probably should have expanded on this to begin with, the reason why I ask is that I'm trying to use Apache httpClient inside the restlet but I'm not able to to get it to work. If that *is* what you're supposed to do, then it's probably a different question altogether.

Comment: Shouldn't you user a ClientResource? http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/jse/api/org/restlet/resource/ClientResource.html

Comment: Your Android app will `POST` to the Restlet server, and then your Restlet server will `POST` to other server, that will forward a C2DM push message back to the device? Which post you don't know how to do?

Comment: It's the POST to google from the restlet I'm failing at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I was doing is the right way to do it after all, I've got Apache HttpClient set up and working in a seperate thread to do the push. For some reason it fails due to a peer exception (which is the exception I was getting initially), but I've got around that by automatically trusting the SSL certificate. Why that was happening with the C2DM address I really have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java's native HttpURLConnection object:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Follow the implementation guidelines provided by Google:  http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#push

Comment: I tried and failed with httpclient, it kept throwing errors despite being the exact same code working with GWT (I can't remember what it was exactly), will try swapping it in with HttpURLconnection.